# Passing environment variables as rake arguments?

Tags: ruby, cmd, escaping, rake

I am trying to run a rake task that takes two parameters. These parameters are already stored as environment variables. I am getting what seems to be an escaping issue. What is wrong with this.

```
rake deploy:web_server[%parameter1%,%parameter2%]
```

I am getting this error message when I run this, where is my last squared bracket disappearing to?

**Don't know how to build task 'deploy:web_server[param1_val,param2val'**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out that my **%parameter2%** environment value had a trailing space at the end. That is what was causing the issue. Have to be careful with spaces for environment variables.